# YouTube Iframe API to handle multiple players is not working on IE/Opera

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/krU9K/4/

My WordPress posts will have embed youtube and vimeo videos beneath the post thumbnail, after user clicks on the thumbnail I want it to fadeout and video should start playing.

All embed iframe ids are of this structure `"youtube-{postid}"` or `"vimeo-{postid}"`. So on page load I can check for the id prefix and use youtube/vimeo player api initialization and put them into global `var players - {};` object to hold all players.

Firefox/Chrome works OK, but not on Opera/IE. Operas console gives an error `Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'players[iframeID]' to object`. So it looks like on Opera the object is empty while on FF/Chrome it has all players and works.

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: looks like Opera doesnt call any code inside `$('iframe').each(function() {...});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the **jQuery .each() function** is occurring before the iframes are ready on the page, so wrap a standard jQuery Document Ready Function for that.

Updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/krU9K/17/

Comment: Your fiddle has just saved me several hours of farting around. Thanks very much!!